# Azure App Functions Application 'appname' has shutdown

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am creating an Azure app function to read from an event hub and write to another event hub. Initially, I was only reading from the event hub and logging some message and that was working fine.

Original code

```
        [FunctionName("EHFunction")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [EventHubTrigger("ehquery", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Read event hub event which contains link to a blob with messages. Read messages from the blob storage endpoint.

                    foreach (var blobEntry in blobData)
                    {
                        foreach (var record in blobEntry.Records)
                        {
                            var recordStr = record.ToString();
                            log.LogInformation($"Record: {recordStr}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    log.LogCritical(e.Message);
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }
```

This was working great. Now I updated code to write the records to a new event hub:

```
        [FunctionName("EHFunction")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [EventHubTrigger("ehquery", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events,
            [EventHub("ehquery-output", Connection = "EventHubOutputConnectionAppSetting")] IAsyncCollector<string> outputEvents,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Read event hub event which contains link to a blob with messages. Read messages from the blob storage endpoint.

                    foreach (var blobEntry in blobData)
                    {
                        foreach (var record in blobEntry.Records)
                        {
                            var recordStr = record.ToString();
                            await outputEvents.AddAsync(recordStr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    log.LogCritical(e.Message);
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }
```

When I publish this function, I see the following messages in the eventlog.xml file

```
<EventData>
<Data>Application 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.7.1\64bit\' started successfully.</Data>
<Data>Process Id: 3776.</Data>
<Data>File Version: 13.1.22054.23. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 509f6badec2f3162f0e50330cd9107e5624b379b</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
<EventData>
<Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EHFunction' has shutdown.</Data>
<Data>Process Id: 4624.</Data>
<Data>File Version: 13.1.22054.23. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 509f6badec2f3162f0e50330cd9107e5624b379b</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

This is my local.settings.json for reference

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "EventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://{inputeventhubconnectionstring}",
    "EventHubOutputConnectionAppSetting": "Endpoint=sb://{outputeventhubconnectionstring}",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

Why is the function unable to write to event hub? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Figured it out. I had not defined the new App Setting (EventHubOutputConnectionAppSetting) in the Azure Functions App on the portal. Once I did that, the app started working.

Comment: If the answer was helpful which is suggest by you, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Thank you @Gengis Khan, for the solution that worked for you which you have mentioned in your comment. I am reposting the same solution so that other SO community members might benefit from it.*

> Why is the function unable to write to event hub? What am I doing
> wrong?

To resolve the above issue ,When deploying Azure function with EventHub as in `local.settings.json` we provide the value for  `eventhubOutputConnectionAppSetting`.***So when deploying function app to azure it can't read `local.settings.json` file we need to add new App settings in the Function on Portal(via *Configuration->New Application Settings*) itself by providing the correct value for the `eventhubOutputConnectionAppSetting` and save it.***

[image]

*For more information please refer this* [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486843/azure-function-app-does-not-trigger-by-event-hub) *for the similar issue*.